# Website App smart lock password association not confirmed yet

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-play-services, google-identity, google-smartlockpasswords

I have implemented smart-lock in my android app and submitted form for website app password association. As this feature is not yet released to production I have uploaded apk to beta track with the changes mentioned in [**Enable automatic sign-in across apps and websites**](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites).

My website url is https://secure.transfast.com/login

and asset link file is uploaded on the server [here](https://secure.transfast.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json)

Its been week since form is submitted. Still have not received any confirmation nor if there are any mistakes.

What is the best way to resolve or communicate with the team?

Comment: Your asset linking file (https://secure.transfast.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json ) is missing the get_login_creds relationship statement, you need an entries with this for both your website and app, please follow step one in the instructions: https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites

Comment: @StevenSoneff - I have submitted form again today. How many days usually it takes for reply? In case of failure , can you please reply so that I will submit form again with correction?

Comment: @StevenSoneff -  can you please confirm and revert. My production release date is approaching soon and this has been pending from long time.

Comment: @Steven 
I have updated app to alpha version, with below link in android manifest file,
How much time will it takes for google?

Link :https://auth-test.centurylink.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json.

Link: https://auth-test.centurylink.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json.

Comment: @Steven We also facing the same approval time(pushed to alpha channel) taking too long and also no reply on that.

Comment: @Steven can you please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77758835/saved-password-between-app-and-website-is-not-sync

Answer (score 1):

You need to publish your app to the public channel, unfortunately publishing it to beta isn't enough for the linking to be picked up. Once that's done, the link will be picked up automatically within two business days.

Comment: Thomas Thrainer -  as per documentation they said publishing to beta or alpha channel is also fine.  My production app is live and changes related to smart lock are published in beta channel. I have submitted this form at-least 4-5 times. Never received any reply. In case if something wrong, it should be intimated. This is lengthy process and needs to be rectified.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation is out of date in this regard (will be fixed soon). You need to publish the app with the smart lock related changes to the public channel.

Comment: - my app is live from last 4 days. But still its not picking up the association. Do I need to submit form even though its optional?

Comment: Your robots.txt disallows indexing of the .well-know/assetlinks.json file, that's why the association isn't picked up.

Please follow the steps outlined at https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites (see "Ensure that your host permits Google to retrieve your Digital Asset Link file") to make sure that the assetlink file is crawlable.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with json file access. Our file has just updated contents for website-app association. With same file contents, deep linking is working for our website banner and app opens seamlessly without any issue.

Comment: Your robots.txt (https://secure.transfast.com/robots.txt) contains this:

`User-agent: *`
`Disallow: /`

This causes the credential sharing functionality to not work. Note that the mechanism for verifying deep linking is different. You need to allow crawling of you assetlinks.json file, otherwise credential sharing won't work (as pointed out in the docs).

Comment: @ThomasThrainer We have also pushed the app in the alpha channel..but before going to the production channel we need to do testing right? How to do that?