# Saved password between app and website is not sync

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-identity

I am trying to sync password between our website and our Android App.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites) document, I have done all required changes.

My website is [here](https://www.nationale-loterij.be/).

Digital asset link file is uploaded on [this server](https://www.nationale-loterij.be/.well-known/assetlinks.json).

Here is the [robots.txt](https://www.nationale-loterij.be/robots.txt) file

In Manifest I have added below code.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />
```

in String.xml

```
<string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">
        [{
            \"include\": \"https://www.nationale-loterij.be/.well-known/assetlinks.json\"
        }]
    </string>
```

App has been published to play-store in public channel, before 2 days.

How much time it takes to sync password b/w Web and App?
Or maybe I have done something wrong?

I am trying to sync password between our website and our Android App.